# How can I change time text color?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I use react-native-gifted-chat for my chat. I want to change time font color. I changed it as the doc said, but its not changing. I want both time colors are black.
using "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.1"

```
  const renderTime = (props) => {
    return (
      <Time
      {...props}
        textStyle={{
          left: {
            color: 'black',
          },
          right: {
            color: 'black',
          },
        }}
      />
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you need to pass [`timeTextStyle`](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/blob/master/src/Time.tsx#L89) instead of `textStyle`.

Try:

```js
  const renderTime = (props) => {
    return (
      <Time
      {...props}
        timeTextStyle={{
          left: {
            color: 'black',
          },
          right: {
            color: 'black',
          },
        }}
      />
    );
  };
```